# Difference between sql Data type and sql type?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been reading in the mysql documentation that if two columns are combined by the  UNION operator and have different data types then their types are considered!

Wondering what's the difference between type and data type?

Comment: They are the same thing.

Comment: ""If the data types of corresponding SELECT columns do not match, the types and lengths of the columns in the UNION result take into account the values retrieved by all of the SELECT statements"".
This was the same word as in MySQl doc

Answer (score 0):

The point is that when doing UNION, the data types are considered.  For example if you are doing a UNION of a varchar and a number into the same field - this may throw an error.

Here is an example in Oracle, I dont have a MySQL environment available.

This SQL fails with 'ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression':

```
select 1 from dual
union
select 'foo' from dual;
```

You can work around this by casting the number as a string:

```
select '1' from dual
union
select 'foo' from dual;
```

Comment: But actually the exact same thing worked in MySQL, I got the output in sequel pro and on more what's the difference between type and datatype?

Comment: @Naveen "Type" and "datatype" are the same thing.  It's somewhat confusing but common for programmers to omit the word "data" from the word "datatype".